# How to compare different stock indexes?

Tags: stock-markets, index-fund, market-indexes, growth-rate

I'm trying to understand how to measure the growth of a particular stock index over a certain period of time, e.g. 5 years.

As far as I understand, for calculating the total growth, you need to do

```
((end - begin) / begin) * 100
```

Being `end` and `begin` the final and initial value (respectively) of the index in question, over the selected period of time (in this example 5 years from now)

According to google, comparing `S&P 500 (USA)`, `FTSE 100 (UK)` and `DAX 30 (GER)`, from 5 years ago until now, I obtain:

FTSE 100: `((7344 - 6527) / 6527.0) * 100.0 = 12.51723609621572`

DAX 30: `((12468 - 9490) / 9490.) * 100. = 31.38040042149631`

S&P 500: `((2992 - 1982) / 1982.) * 100.0 = 50.95862764883956`

This seems to be a nonsense. Are the above results correct?

If so, **under which circumstances would it be better to invest in the `DAX 30` or `FTSE 100`**, given that their growth is far less than the `S&P 500`? (Even taking into account tax free bank accounts in your country + avoid fees in changing currencies)

Comment: "This seems to be a nonsense." **Why** do you think it's nonsense?

Comment: You picks yer metrics and you pays yer money. What are you trying to measure?

Comment: @RonJohn I thought that because it seemed to me a very (insane) difference between these stock indexes. I still can't understand how someone could want to invest in DAX 30 or FTSE 100, I must be missing something.

Comment: @Lawrence I was trying to imagine which index stock is better, given the circumstance that if live for instance in the UK, you can open an ISA that is tax free up to £20k yearly, and you don't have problems with currency exchange. But  given the numbers above, it makes absolutely no sense to invest in some index other than the S&P or similar, as far as I understand, even taking into account the tax relief etc.

Comment: @Martel One of the problems with historical data is that past trends don't determine future trends.

Comment: "I thought that because it seemed to me a very (insane) difference between these stock indexes."  Different stocks perform differently.  Different indexes track different stocks.  Ergo, different indexes will perform differently.

Comment: More than that, you are comparing broad equity funds in different economies with different currencies. There's no reason to assume that any of them will perform the same going forward.

Comment: @DStanley then, under certain circumstances, it would make sense to invest in DAX 30 for instance. Could you put an example please?

Comment: It might make sense _if you live in Germany_. Note, though, that this is analogous to the DOW 30 from your other question, and has some of the same limitations when comparing to the S&P 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like the Yahoo Finance tracker to get a graph to show the comparison. [Example](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/chart?p=%5EGSPC#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%3D). This approach has the advantage of letting you adjust the length of the time frame and slide it around to see how these indices have performed at different points.

One thing not captured by this approach will be the difference in the currency exchange rates. I live in Canada but hold VTI which tracks the US stock market. When the market remains constant but the Canadian dollar drops I see a gain in my fund.

When applying your formula to the actual funds themselves don't forget that these funds pay dividends as well (which aren't captured well in the Yahoo finance chart). Try using [this website](https://dqydj.com/etf-return-calculator/) to assess the performance of the actual ETFs you'd be buying.

Once you actually buy some funds you may want to use something like the website [Sharesight](https://portfolio.sharesight.com) to keep track of your investments as it actively tracks dividend payments and currency gains in addition to growth in the equity itself. It's also free if you're only tracking <10 funds.

Comment: Why use Sharesight to track dividend payments, when your broker's website shows dividend payments?

Comment: @RonJohn I purchase Vanguard funds through my bank so that I can see the balance on all my accounts in the same location. My bank's website has a pretty terrible layout though so I use Sharesight to get better visuals.

Comment: @Dougan you'd probably be a lot better off buying more of the fund(s) than paying for Sharesight, or any other paid portfolio tracker.

Comment: @quid Absolutely. Don't pay for something you can get for free. Sharesight is free if you track 10 or fewer stock tickers.

Comment: @RonJohn. You can't buy through Vanguard directly in Canada (where I live) [(Source)](https://www.vanguardcanada.ca/individual/how-to-invest.htm). Fortunately my bank offers free currency exchange so it almost offsets the added brokerage fee of $6.95.

Comment: You should move south where it's warm, and they don't play silly games like hockey!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice simple [DRIP Calculator](https://www.dividendchannel.com/drip-returns-calculator/)  that will allow you to pick the time frame and provide historical results for dividend reinvestment and without it.  You can verify your numbers easily: